# Prayer, invalid or valid?

Tags: salat, sunnah

To answer this question you have to read the text below, and don't give me your opinion please (not to be rude of course) but this is not an opinion based question...Which many people always think...

So, I pray like Sunni’s basically...

And actually Shia prayer is kind of the same

But the problem is that some sentences are a little bit different towards each other in Sunni and Shia prayer...

For example:

»In rukoo':

In Sunni prayer I say 3 times "subhana rabbi alhadiem",

While in Shia prayer I used to say 
"subhana rabbi alhadiem wa bi hamdih, allahoema salli 'ala Mohammed wa 'ala alih Mohammed" 
I said it only once

»And while I'm in sujood:

I say in Sunni prayers 3 times "subhana rabbi al ah'la",

While in Shia prayer I said once
"Subhana rabbi al ah'la wa bi hamdih, allahoema sallih 'ala Muhammed wa 'ala alih Muhammad"

»And the position between the two times you do sujood (when you sit on your knees:

I say in Sunni prayer 2 times "rabbi ighfirlee",

While in Shia prayer I used to say "astaghfiruka ya rabbi wa atubuh ileïk" only once

»And after sujood in the second rak'aa:

I say in say in Sunni prayers...

"At tahiyatu lillahi salawati wa tayyibaatu
As salamu aleika ayyuha an nabiyuh wa rahmatullahi wa barakatuhu
Wa a Salamu alaina wa 'ala hibadi lahi salihien
Ashhadoe an la ilaha il Allah wa ashadoe ana Mohammedan habdoe'hoe wa rassulhoe"

While in Shia prayer I used to say...

"Ashadoe an la ilaha il Allah wa ashadoe ana Mohammedan habdoe'hoe wa rassulhoe
Allahuma salli 'ala Mohammed wa 'ala alih Mohammed"

And in the last rakaat after sujood:

I say in Sunni prayer I say...

"At tahiyatu lillahi salawati wa tayyibaatu
As salamu haleika ayyu an nabiyuh wa rahmatullahi wa barakatu
As a Salamu halaina wa 'ala hibadi lahi salihien
Ashhadoe an la ilaha il Allah wa ashadoe ana Mohammedan habdoe'hoe wa rassulhoe
Allahuma salli 'ala Mohammed wa 'ala alih Mohammed
Kama sallayta 'ala ibrahim wa 'ala alih ibrahim, wa innaka hameedum majeeed
Allahuma barik 'ala Mohammed wa 'ala alih Mohammed
Kama barakta 'ala ibrahim wa 'ala alih ibrahim, wa inaka hameedum majeed"

Then I say "a salamu haleikum to the right and left
Then I'm done with my prayer

While in Shia I used to say...

Ashhadoe an la ilaha il Allah wa ashadoe ana Mohammedan habdoe'hoe wa rassulhoe
Allahuma salli 'ala Mohammed wa 'ala alih Mohammed
A Salam muhaleika ayu an nabiyuh wa rahmatullahi wa barakatuh 
Wa a salam muhaleina wa 'ala hibadih lahi salihien
Wa a salam muhaleikum wa rahmatullahi wa barakatuhu"

Then I said 3 times "Allahu Akbar"
And each time saying the takbeer at the end of prayer I used to wave my hands above my shoulders (just like you do when you change your position to rukoo')

So is one of the prayer invalid, because of the difference?

Comment: And at the very end of the prayer?

Comment: Brother, with all respect, there is a difference in the tashahud